# VBA Macro to delete rows to a default table size

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that will add lines as the second to bottom row of a table gets filled up but i want to add a second macro to resize the table to 12 rows and 11 columns when the table is over 12 rows and there is no data in the additional rows.

Here is the Macro to add rows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Declaration of Variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Set sht as worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Set Lastrow
    LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count
    LastRow = LastRow + 4

    'Check - is someone entering in account name for the last open row
    If Me.Range("B" & LastRow - 1) = "" Then 'User is not entering in account name in last open row, exit sub
        Exit Sub
    Else 'User is entering in account name in last open row - create new row
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'turn off event handlers which allows sub to execute
        Rows(LastRow).Select 'select the summary row
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert 'insert row above
        ActiveSheet.Range("F" & LastRow & ":L" & LastRow).Select 'select formulas only
        Selection.FillDown 'fill the formulas in
        ActiveSheet.Range("C" & LastRow - 1).Select 'on the row that is being entered, select Pipeline Stage Cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'turn on event handlers
    End If
End Sub
```

I found this macro online but I cant seem to manipulate it to do what I want, I want the macro to resize the table to 12 rows by 11 columns when L14 < 1

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows1()
    'Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

    'We use Long in case they have over 32,767 rows selected.
    Dim i As Long

    'We turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False

    'We work backwards because we are deleting rows.
    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I find it difficult to think my way into your project because the logic appears a little warped. At the core of your project stands a table which, however, you never use. You fill in extra rows above the summary row, but then you expect these rows to be blank so that they should be removed. I recommend that you work either with the sheet or with the table. That will simplify the process of determining which rows to delete. Then set a time (an event) when a check should be carried out by which to remove blank rows. After that, removing them will be easy.

Comment: I am making this for someone else so I will not be around to delete extra rows when necessary so thats why I am thinking like this. The table is to track incoming fees from various people throughout the period of the month. Sometimes they will go over the amount of fixed rows in the table so I got the macro to add rows as needed but I dont want the table to get ridiculously out of hand so when those fees are no longer coming in and those additional rows are not needed - I want the table to delete the extra rows to make it look cleaner.

Comment: How is the process of adding a row triggered? It shouldn't be possible to add a row while a blank one exists. Now you insert a new row and select its first cell. Instead, check first if a blank row exists and select the first cell in that row - without adding a new one.

Comment: The table is set up as row1 = headers, rows 2-11 = data entry points, row 12 = totals (summary). Its set up so when the user types in the first entry point in row 11 it automatically creates a new data entry point row and thus makes the table 13 rows by 11 columns but what I want to do is when those additional rows are no longer needed, the table resets to 12 by 11

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub DeleteTableRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
For r = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 12 Step -1
    If Application.CountIf(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(r), "?*") = 0 Then
        tbl.ListRows(r).Delete
    End If
Next r
For c = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count To 12 Step -1
    tbl.ListColumns(c).Delete
Next c
End Sub
```

If you want to include an IF statement to check the table rows, you can try it like this...

```
Sub DeleteTableRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim r As Long, c As Long, tblRows As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
tblRows = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
If tblRows > 12 Then
    For r = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 12 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(r), "?*") = 0 Then
            tbl.ListRows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
    For c = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count To 12 Step -1
        tbl.ListColumns(c).Delete
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that's almost exactly what im looking for. Is there to automate it, maybe through an IF statement saying when LastRow - 2 is <1, it will automatically resize it using the same idea as above?

Comment: What do you mean by LastRow - 2 is <1? Do you mean if LastRow - 2 is >12 then delete the rows?

Comment: If the table is larger than 12 rows and the last two rows besides the summary row has no data in them, it will reset to 12 rows by 11 columns

Comment: Edited the solution and added the second code with an IF statement.